# VS is reporting object file to be old when it was just built/created. How can I turn off /LTCG to test with?

Tags: c++, linker

I'm attempting to build [Pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin), with the Python pybind11 'extension', for Windows.
This is a cmake based project that I'm trying to build using VS2017. 
(I had a go using MinGW64 and CodeBlocks but had too many problems)
I seem close to getting to the end but then stumble when linking.

VS is reporting that a file, (attach.cpp.obj) was created with an older compiler. But when I look at the timestamp of that file it was just created. This is also a freshly cloned instance of the Pangolin project and I haven't used any other compiler/linker with it.

These are the actual error messages:

```
  [46/46] cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\software_installs\VS2017Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_dll --intdir=src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir --manifests  -- D:\software_installs\VS2017Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\attach.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\colour.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\datalog.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\display.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\gl.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\gl_draw.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\glsl.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\handler.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\image.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\image_view.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\opengl_render_state.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\params.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\pixel_format.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\plotter.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\var.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\video.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\view.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\viewport.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\widget.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\window.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin_module.cpp.obj  /out:src\pypangolin.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /implib:src\pypangolin.lib /pdb:src\pypangolin.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL -LIBPATH:C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\Lib\100177~1.0\ucrt\x64 C:\Python36\libs\Python36.lib src\pangolin.lib opengl32.lib glu32.lib C:\Python36\libs\Python36.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\glew.lib mf.lib mfplat.lib mfreadwrite.lib mfuuid.lib strmiids.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libpng16_static.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libzlibstatic.a C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libjpeg.a kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib  && cd ."
  FAILED: src/pypangolin.cp36-win_amd64.pyd 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\software_installs\VS2017Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_dll --intdir=src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir --manifests  -- D:\software_installs\VS2017Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\attach.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\colour.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\datalog.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\display.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\gl.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\gl_draw.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\glsl.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\handler.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\image.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\image_view.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\opengl_render_state.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\params.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\pixel_format.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\plotter.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\var.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\video.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\view.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\viewport.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\widget.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\window.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin_module.cpp.obj  /out:src\pypangolin.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /implib:src\pypangolin.lib /pdb:src\pypangolin.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL -LIBPATH:C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\Lib\100177~1.0\ucrt\x64 C:\Python36\libs\Python36.lib src\pangolin.lib opengl32.lib glu32.lib C:\Python36\libs\Python36.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\glew.lib mf.lib mfplat.lib mfreadwrite.lib mfuuid.lib strmiids.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libpng16_static.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libzlibstatic.a C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libjpeg.a kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib  && cd ."
  LINK Pass 1: command "D:\software_installs\VS2017Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\attach.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\colour.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\datalog.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\display.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\gl.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\gl_draw.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\glsl.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\handler.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\image.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\image_view.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\opengl_render_state.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\params.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\pixel_format.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\plotter.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\var.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\video.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\view.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\viewport.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\widget.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\window.cpp.obj src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin_module.cpp.obj /out:src\pypangolin.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /implib:src\pypangolin.lib /pdb:src\pypangolin.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL -LIBPATH:C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\Lib\100177~1.0\ucrt\x64 C:\Python36\libs\Python36.lib src\pangolin.lib opengl32.lib glu32.lib C:\Python36\libs\Python36.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\glew.lib mf.lib mfplat.lib mfreadwrite.lib mfuuid.lib strmiids.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libpng16_static.lib C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libzlibstatic.a C:\Users\Fred\CMakeBuilds\2a8b3e97-005e-803f-a2dd-1ca65471a4a2\install\x64-Release\lib\libjpeg.a kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir/intermediate.manifest src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1257) with the following output:
  attach.cpp.obj : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
C:\WINDOWS\system32\LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/LTCG' specification
C:\WINDOWS\system32\EXEC : fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'src\CMakeFiles\pypangolin.dir\python\pypangolin\attach.cpp.obj' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
C:\WINDOWS\system32\LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have tried to find where to turn off '/LTCG' but it seems hard to do as its a cmake project.
I must confess that I have had to rename one or two .lib files and copy in the odd precompiled .lib to get this far, due to mismatches in CMakeLists etc.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Or at least how I can test link without /LTCG?

Comment: I abandoned this and installed Lubunto on an old laptop I had. It built perfectly without any trouble on that.